# Где брать библиотеки и классы для php?

Tags: php

Ходят слухи - для php написано множество библиотек и функций, расширяющих возможности языка. Однако нет какого-то единого репозитория. Или есть?

Comment: https://github.com/ там есть все, почти

Comment: Ну к примеру https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php/blob/master/README.md#php-books

Comment: https://packagist.org

Answer (score 0):

Установите на свой сервер composer
https://getcomposer.org/download/

и устанавливайте в пару кликов необходимые пакеты из репозитория: https://packagist.org/

либо ищите на https://github.com/search?q=php